# Asp .Net SDK 3.10408

Tags: asp.net-core

I run the code
`dotnet new global.json --sdk-version 3.1.408`
but I need to downgrade sdk-version 3.1.0

I deleted global.json folder again

project are developed in ASP .NetCore 3.1
then I try the `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.1.0`

If I run `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name EmployeeController -m Employee -dc AppDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries`

I got the following error:

> A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [3.1.0]
> from [/home/dir_name/app1/global.json] was not found Install the
> [3.1.0] .NET Core SDK or update [dir_name/app1/global.json] with an
> installed .NET Core SDK:
> 3.1.408 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/123/sdk]

Comment: your project file might be referencing older .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message said, the 3.1.0 .NET Core SDK was not found, I assume you didn't install the 3.1.0 version .NET Core SDK.

Try to use the following command to check the installed SDK version:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Then, you could [download the 3.1.0 version .NET Core SDK and Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) and install it.